# Count number of records in subgroup while keeping a number of records in a group

Tags: sql, group-by, grouping

I have a table with the following structure (it's a simplified version, just to show the idea):

```
name    |  city
------------------
John    | New York
Thomas  | Berlin
Hans    | Berlin
Boris   | Moscow
Boris   | Moscow
Vasiliy | Moscow
```

I can use `group by` to get a total number of people in every city, like so:

`select count(*) from my_table group by city`

But I need a little bit more and I can' wrap my head around it: I need to get a number of all people with the same name in the same city while keeping a total number of people in that city. This is how the result should look like:

```
name    | totalWithThisName | totalInThisCity | city
--------------------------------------------------------
John    |         1         |        1        | New York
Thomas  |         1         |        2        | Berlin
Hans    |         1         |        2        | Berlin
Boris   |         2         |        3        | Moscow
Vasiliy |         1         |        3        | Moscow
```

I know that I can take a raw data from db, and make calculations in my java program, but it would be great to make it in a plain SQL.

**Update:** I'm using `mysql` and I can't use `over` clause.

Comment: This is very similar:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503959/how-to-count-occurrences-of-a-column-value-efficiently-in-sql

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution I've made so far is to use subquery with `join`. It looks like this:

```
select
    name,
    city,  
    count(*) as totalWithThisName,
    T.totalInThisCity
from 
    my_table 
    join (select
              count(*) as totalInThisCity,
              city
          from
              my_table
          group by city) T on my_table.city = T.city
group by 
    city, name;
```

Comment: this is an old answer but one thing I do not understand is grouping is done on city, name but T.totalInThisCity is neither aggregated not grouped. How does that work.

Answer (score 5):

```
select  distinct name
,       count(*) over (partition by Name) as TotalWithThisName
,       count(*) over (partition by City) as TotalInThisCity
,       city
from    YourTable
```

Comment: I forgot to tell that I'm using `mysql` and I can't use `over` clause.

Comment: See this then for a workaround http://explainextended.com/2009/03/10/analytic-functions-first_value-last_value-lead-lag/