# Ordering records by number of occurrences in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails 4.0 I have this table and I want to sort it by the number of occurrences of location_id. In this case the most popular location_id is 3. I want to sort my table in descending order starting with all records with location_id: 3 on the top.

Table Geochecks-

```
┌────┬─────────┬─────────────┬─────────────────────┬────────────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ id │ user_id │ location_id │ message             │ created_at         │ updated_at          │
├────┼─────────┼─────────────┼─────────────────────┼────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ 1  ╎ 14      ╎ 2           ╎ Test test t         ╎ 2013-07-23 13:3... ╎ 2013-07-23 13:37... │
│ 2  ╎ 12      ╎ 3           ╎                     ╎ 2013-07-23 13:5... ╎ 2013-07-23 13:54... │
│ 3  ╎ 15      ╎ 2           ╎ <html lang="en" ... ╎ 2013-07-25 08:5... ╎ 2013-07-25 08:57... │
│ 4  ╎ 12      ╎ 3           ╎ Ohohohooh           ╎ 2013-07-25 11:3... ╎ 2013-07-25 11:37... │
│ 5  ╎ 12      ╎ 3           ╎ Pff kjasakljdfas... ╎ 2013-07-25 11:3... ╎ 2013-07-25 11:37... │
│ 6  ╎ 15      ╎ 4           ╎                     ╎ 2013-07-25 13:5... ╎ 2013-07-25 13:54... │
│ 7  ╎ 13      ╎ 4           ╎ dasfdasfdasfdasf    ╎ 2013-07-25 14:3... ╎ 2013-07-25 14:30... │
│ 8  ╎ 13      ╎ 3           ╎                     ╎ 2013-07-25 14:3... ╎ 2013-07-25 14:30... │
│ 9  ╎ 13      ╎ 2           ╎ Test check message  ╎ 2013-07-25 14:3... ╎ 2013-07-25 14:31... │
│ 10 ╎ 13      ╎ 5           ╎ asdfdasfdasfdasfa   ╎ 2013-07-25 14:4... ╎ 2013-07-25 14:42... │
│ 11 ╎ 16      ╎ 7           ╎ Hohohooh            ╎ 2013-07-26 07:5... ╎ 2013-07-26 07:50... │
└────┴─────────┴─────────────┴─────────────────────┴────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

I know how to count them the by for ex.: `Geochecks.where(location_id: 3).count #=> 4` and thought about a loop which will do `.where().count` requests through the whole table and after that compare the results to find the biggest one, but I am pretty sure that there is a cleverer solution.

Desired output: The desired output should be a list of the location_id's in descending order. In this case it should be: `3, 2, 4, 5, 7`

Comment: I think you will need to have an SQL query where you first perform group, count, and order and then join result of this query to the table again to use it as an order.

Comment: I do not really understand SQL queries very well. Could you provide me with any examples? Thanks

Comment: That's the point. If you have no idea how to do it I would encourage you to learn SQL first. Doing things you don't understand is not a way to go. You may try going a little around and perform this with Rails, let me write an answer.

Comment: Hmm, ok, so if you were joining some other table this would be possible in Rails (order records from table A based on count from B) but I can't figure out how to make it on a single table without self join.

Comment: Got it! http://stackoverflow.com/a/17879951/2422778

Comment: But you said that it is possible with custom SQL. I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503959/how-to-count-occurrences-of-a-column-value-efficiently-in-sql saying how to count occurrences of a column, but I have no idea how to order them

Comment: So look at my answer, see if it works. If it does I will explain in detail what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, doing it with SQL as I pointed out in a comment would be rather complicated and requires good knowledge of SQL. But with a little time in `rails c` I found a way to do it in Rails!
The result of this query will be Locations not Geochecks, but I don't think it will be a problem for you.

```
Location.joins(:geochecks).order('COUNT(geochecks.id) DESC').group('location.id')
```

Comment: This one simply returned my locations table in its default order. Not very sure how is that helpful to sort Gechecks

Comment: I just want output a list of the location_ids in descending order according to the number of occurrences for each location. I will put the desired output above.

Comment: Ok, and if you run `Location.joins(:geochecks).order('COUNT(geochecks.id) DESC').group('location.id').map(&:geochecks).map(&:count)` do you get an array of descending values? Please add result of this in a comment!

Comment: Here is the result just in case you want to see it - `=> [4, 3, 2, 2, 1]
`

Answer (score -1):

I think it should work:

```
Table.find(:all, :order => "location_id_count DESC")
```

Comment: When I try this the console returns Error: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: location_id_count. So it doesn't understand what does _count mean