# how to get the maximum occurrence value from a table for a combination?

Tags: sql

I have the following table;

```
column 1  column 2   column 3
1         2          X
1         2          X
1         2          Y

1         3          Z
1         3          X
```

I need to write an SQL query to get the output as;

```
1         2         X (because X is the maximum occurrence)
1         3         Z or X(because number of occurrence of Z or X is same)
```

How do i do this ?

Comment: I'm sure you could work something out with a combination of `GROUP BY ColumnName` and `COUNT(column)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503959/how-to-count-occurrences-of-a-column-value-efficiently-in-sql

Comment: i need the value which has the highest number of occurance.

Answer (score 0):

I think i have a solution for you, try this script using the functions RANK(), ROW_NUMBER() & DENSE_RANK(), you choose the function that fits with your needs :

```
with temp as (
select 1 as col1, 2 AS col2, 'X' as col3 union all
select 1 as col1, 2 AS col2, 'Y' as col3 union all
select 1 as col1, 2 AS col2, 'X' as col3 union all
select 1 as col1, 3 AS col2, 'Z' as col3 union all
select 1 as col1, 3 AS col2, 'T' as col3 union all
select 1 as col1, 3 AS col2, 'Y' as col3 union all
select 1 as col1, 3 AS col2, 'Y' as col3 union all
select 1 as col1, 4 AS col2, 'Y' as col3 union all
select 1 as col1, 4 AS col2, 'W' as col3)
,temp2 AS (
select
     col1
    ,col2
    ,col3
    ,COUNT(1) nb_occurence
    ,RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY col1,col2 ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC) Ordre_RANK
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col1,col2 ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC) Ordre_ROW_NUMBER
    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY col1,col2 ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC) Ordre_DENSE_RANK
from temp
GROUP BY
     col1
    ,col2
    ,col3 )

SELECT *
FROM temp2
--WHERE Ordre_RANK = 1
--WHERE Ordre_ROW_NUMBER = 1
--WHERE Ordre_DENSE_RANK = 1
```

I hope this will help you.