# How to format and print a result of sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I recently got this question on interview which I failed to answer. The question was to list the number of duplicates that appear in a column employer like from this table

```
id  |   employer   |  employee
1   |    isro      |      dude1
2   |    isro      | dude 2
3   |    cnd       | dude 3
4   |   df         | dsfdef
5   | dfdf         | dfdfd
...
```

so the result should be  like

```
isro  = 2
df    = 4
dfsf  = 6
```

how do i achieve this?
I know there is count(*) which i could use with select statement with where clause, but how do i achieve the above result.

Comment: It is unclear how that result should come out of a query. You will have to explain the logic behind.

Comment: Or is this question _really_ just about grouping by employer and counting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HAVING` clause can be used to filter on aggregated values:

```
SELECT employer, COUNT(*)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY employer
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Since I only need to print the number of times the employer occurs in my table , shouldn't I use count(employer). Whats the difference between count(*) and count(column name)? and Why is Having clause included,  "having count(*) > 1" will list only the values having duplicates in the employer column? `select employer, count(employer) from table group by employer ; ` is this correct answer for my question?

Comment: @MahabPhoenixKhan `COUNT(*)` will count all rows, whereas `COUNT(employer)` will exclude from the count any rows where `employer` is `NULL`.  Since you're `GROUPING BY employer`, a `NULL` value for `employer` would be returned with a count of `0`.  If it's never `NULL` there will be no difference between `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(employer).  Here's a simple example to demonstrate:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5f029/2/0

Answer (score 0):

assuming TableName is the name of the table you want to select from, this would be your answer.

```
SELECT employer, count(employer) 
  FROM TableName 
  GROUP BY employer
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

here is an answer to a very similar question that has some more info for you.

[How to count occurrences of a column value efficiently in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503959/how-to-count-occurrences-of-a-column-value-efficiently-in-sql)