# Add additional column to give a count on number of occurance on an existing column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an existing table with many fields of personal data.
For each personal records, there is a unique reference number

I am trying to do a script that can add a new column onto the existing table 
This new added column is to hold number count on the number of time the unique reference on each row have came up.

For example:

```
---------------------------
UniqueID | PersonlData1 | PersonalData2 |
A        | A1           | A2            |
B        | B1           | B2            |
C        | C1           | C2            |
D        | D1           | D2            |
A        | AA1          | AA2           |
D        | DD1          | DD2           |
```

To become:

```
---------------------------
UniqueID | PersonlData1 | PersonalData2 | CountID |
A        | A1           | A2            | 2       |
B        | B1           | B2            | 1       |
C        | C1           | C2            | 1       |
D        | D1           | D2            | 2       |
A        | AA1          | AA2           | 2       |
D        | DD1          | DD2           | 2       |
```

Comment: Which database are you using? Since the answer will be different for each database. But anyway, search for `add column` or its analogue for your RDBMS.

Comment: SQL server management studio

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count occurrences of a column value efficiently in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503959/how-to-count-occurrences-of-a-column-value-efficiently-in-sql)

Comment: Calling a column `UniqueID` is bad enough (since id implies uniqueness), having duplicate values on that column is so absurd it's actually a little funny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try using `COUNT` as an analytic function here:

```
SELECT
    UniqueID,
    Person1Data1,
    PersonalData2,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY UniqueID) CountID
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: I wonder if now I have another fields called "Date".
and this is actually in the date format say DD/MM/YYYYY
What I want to do is everytime when I see the CountID > 1
I only want to take the records from one specific date
say one date is 11/12/2019, and the one I want to take from is 12/12/2019?

Could this be done? thank you

Comment: @Ekim your requirements are met, post another question with new table values. Accept this answer