# How to count each value in multiple rows and same column?

Tags: sql, database, azure-sql-database, ssms

I have the problem to count the number of each tags.

For example:

```
    tags
0  a,b,c,d
1  a,b
2  c,d
3  a,c
```

My Expected Results:

```
tags   count
  a      3
  b      2
  c      3
  d      2
```

Comment: which rdbms it is ?

Comment: @VenkataramanR azure sql db

Comment: ok. added answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to achieve this

```
SELECT
value, count(*) as countOfTags
FROM
(
VALUES
(0,  'a,b,c,d')
,(1,  'a,b'    )
,(2,  'c,d'    )
,(3,  'a,c'    )
) as t(id, tags)
CROSS APPLY 
string_split(tags,',')
GROUP BY value;
```

The result set

```
+-------+-------------+
| value | countOfTags |
+-------+-------------+
| a     |           3 |
| b     |           2 |
| c     |           3 |
| d     |           2 |
+-------+-------------+
```

Comment: Please mark it as answer, so that it is helpful for others in future.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverFlow!

Do you have an example of your code? Your tag says "SQL" so that's what I'll assume. I can't tell much from your question right now as you haven't given us enough info to help. It would be nice for future questions to add a bit more detail as to what you've tried to do already.

Still, I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503959/how-to-count-occurrences-of-a-column-value-efficiently-in-sql) that's on counting occurrences of column values, so it could answer your question. You can always edit your questions for clarity if need be!