# SQL Code to filter based on dates for each unique record

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a table that looks something like this, lets call it TABLE_1:

```
| Customer_ID | Date_Start | Date_End   |
| c1          | 2017-09-24 | 2017-03-24 |
| c2          | 2017-03-28 | 2017-09-28 |
| c3          | 2018-12-22 | 2019-06-22 |
| c4          | 2017-04-26 | 2017-10-26 |
```

There is another table called TABLE_2 which contains records of all customer IDs for multiple dates. Is there a way in which I can get row using SQL query from TABLE_2 such that I can count how many times each customer ID occurs in the TABLE_2 within the ranges of Date_Start and Date_End based on the above TABLE_1?

Here there is a filter on each customer ID.

Comment: FYI, they are **rows** not "records". As for your question, what have you tried? Why didn't it work? Seems like an `EXISTS` would work. Difficult to know when we have no sample data or expected results.

Comment: @Larnu I have made the edits to the above question.

Comment: *"Here there is a filter on each customer ID."* doesn't address my comment.

Answer (score 0):

This might do it, if I understand the question:

```
SELECT T1.Customer_ID, T1.Date_Start, T1.Date_End, COUNT(*)
FROM Table1 AS T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS T2 
   on T1.Customer_ID=T2.Customer_ID 
      and T2.cust_date BETWEEN T1.Date_Start and T2.Date_Start
```

Answer (score 0):

select distinct Table1.customer_ID
count(Table_2.customer_ID)

from TABLE_1
left join TABLE_2 on TABLE_1_customer_ID = TABLE_2_customer_ID

below will be helpful

[How to count occurrences of a column value efficiently in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503959/how-to-count-occurrences-of-a-column-value-efficiently-in-sql)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

maybe a simple left join will help

```
SELECT A.Customer_ID, COUNT(B.Customer_ID ) as count_of_records
FROM TABLE_1 A LEFT JOIN
TABLE_2 B 
 ON A.Customer_ID =B.Customer_ID 
WHERE B.datecol BETWEEN A.Date_Start AND A.Date_End
GROUP BY A.Customer_ID
```